# Invalid arguments istream read

Tags: c++, eclipse, istream, invalid-argument

I want to read out a file using istream::read(). However I get the error "Invalid arguments" when trying to compile in Eclipse CDT.

Code looks like this

```
int main(){
    std::ifstream list("list", std::fstream::in);

    if( list.is_open() ){
        list.seekg(0, list.end );
        int listlength= list.tellg();

        if(1 <= listlength){
            list.seekg(0, list.beg );
            char* filecon = new char[listlength];

            list.read( filecon, listlength);
        }else{
        }
    }else{
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & read(char *, ?)
'
```

For me read(char *, ?) looks like the problem. Eclipse and the compiler seem unable to get the type of the second argument. Are there some relevant settings in Eclipse that I must change? I have added the "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings" to the Providers in the C/C++ General settings, but that didn't help, unfortunately.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Post compilable code.

Comment: I cannot find any obvious error. The code also compiles fine on my machine.